# How to play mp3 file without exposing source file location?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mp3

I want to play mp3 file (using HTML, JS, jQuery, PHP) but without the possibility that the visitor in the website will be able to get the address of the file and could therefore download it.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Not really possible. You could encrypt the file and decrypt on client, but that's not exactly easy and you cannot prevent downloading the encrypted file.

Comment: I tried to use the embed html tag. But I can download it via this option.

Comment: What about prevent that access to the uploads folder using htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

In short: You can't. Somehow you have to submit the files URL and a user with some background knowledge will use extensions like Firebug to view all made HTTP requests.

Thinking this further: As long as the user is able to listen to the sound file, it somehow has to be sent over the wire. And once it has arrived on the client side you have literally now control what the user does with it.

Comment: What about prevent that access to the uploads folder using htaccess?

Comment: then nobody can access that file including you by http request

Comment: You could try to issue some kind of tokens that can only be used once, but this does not solve the root problem: At some problem the file *will* be transferred and you can't distinguish whether its a download to disk or a listening user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using those technologies, the link will probably always have to be visible, so this isn't really possible.

[Jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) is one option you have that I can think of off the top of my head, if the user has a minimal knowledge about stuff like viewing source, he'll still be able to find the mp3 link, But It'll still keep the majority of people at bay though as they won't know where to look.

If you **REALLY** want to keep it hidden from the user, you could even go as far as embedding the mp3 file in a flash application. This is particularly nasty though, but it would get you what sounds like your desired result.

Comment: What about prevent that access to the uploads folder using htaccess?

Comment: Then the users won't be able to access it, which defeats the point. Bottom line is if a user can listen to it, it will be potentially possible for them to get a copy of the file. You'll never be able to make it 100% secure, so you have to draw a line somewhere. The hardest to crack solution that I can think of that's probably within your capability is to embed the mp3 in a Flash application, this will let users still listen to the file, but not be able to access the mp3 file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a Flash file or something else, or even stream them from an Icecast server, if you just want them to play back

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158657/how-to-prevent-idm-capturing-mp3-files)

Comment: What about prevent that access to the uploads folder using htaccess?